# How to add row with confidence intervals for each column using gtsummary

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, confidence-interval, gtsummary

I am trying to get confidence intervals for each colum in dataset(W,S,F,LF) by addding a row at the end of the table. Is it possible to do this using the gtsummary package?

```
library(gtsummary)

a <- structure(list(SampleDate = structure(c(15710, 15713, 15713, 
15710, 15710, 15713, 15713, 15710, 15708, 15713, 15712, 15708, 
15708, 15713, 15712, 15708), class = "Date"), year = c("2012", 
"2013", "2013", "2012", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
"2012", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013"), F = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 65, 0, 0), W = c(0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), S = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), LF = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))

#  SampleDate year  F W S LF
#1  2013-01-05 2012  0 0 0  1
#2  2013-01-08 2013  1 0 0  0
#3  2013-01-08 2013  0 1 0  0
#4  2013-01-05 2012  0 0 0  1
#5  2013-01-05 2013  0 0 1  0
#6  2013-01-08 2013  1 0 0  0
#7  2013-01-08 2013  0 1 0  0
#8  2013-01-05 2013  0 0 0  1
#9  2013-01-03 2013  0 0 1  0
#10 2013-01-08 2012 22 0 0  0
#11 2013-01-07 2013  0 1 0  0
#12 2013-01-03 2013  0 0 1  0
#13 2013-01-03 2013  0 0 0  1
#14 2013-01-08 2013 65 0 0  0
#15 2013-01-07 2013  0 1 0  0
#16 2013-01-03 2013  0 0 0  1


a %>%
  select(SampleDate) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    missing =  "no",
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})") %>% add_ci()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `W`, `S`, `LF` variables in your data are dichotomous (binary) whereas the `F` variable is not (it's continuous) - this is an assumption from the sample data provided.

Hence, assuming that we want to compute

- the 95% CI of the population mean for `F` and
- the 95% CI of the population proportion for the variables `W`, `S` and `LF`,

first let's observe the following:

The `add_ci()` function computes the confidence interval for proportion for each distinct value of `F` (and not the CI for mean), despite `F` is numeric (most likely it's because of `F` has only 4 different values in the given sample data):

```
a %>% select(F)%>% tbl_summary()%>% add_ci()
```

[image]

If this is not what we want, let's find a workaround with small jitter so that it computes the CI around mean, as shown below:

```
a %>% mutate(F=F+.001*rnorm(nrow(a))) %>% select(F) %>% 
     tbl_summary(statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})") %>% add_ci()
```

[image]

Now, we can compute the desired CI for the columns:

```
b <- a %>%
  mutate(F1=F+0.001*rnorm(nrow(a))) %>% # jitter
  select(F1,W,S,LF) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    missing =  "no",
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})") %>%
  add_ci(pattern = "{stat} ({ci})")
```

Note that `b$table_body` contains the desired CI values:

```
b$table_body
# A tibble: 4 × 7
#  variable var_type    var_label row_type label stat_0  ci_stat_0
#  <chr>    <chr>       <chr>     <chr>    <chr> <chr>   <chr>    
#1 F1       continuous  F1        label    F1    6 (17)  -3.4, 14  # CI or mean
#2 W        dichotomous W         label    W     4 (25%) 8.3%, 53%
#3 S        dichotomous S         label    S     3 (19%) 5.0%, 46%
#4 LF       dichotomous LF        label    LF    5 (31%) 12%, 59%
```

Now, we can add the CIs to the last row in the data frame `a`:

```
rbind(a, c(NA, NA,b$table_body$ci_stat_0))

#   SampleDate year        F         W         S       LF
#1  2013-01-05 2012        0         0         0        1
#2  2013-01-08 2013        1         0         0        0
#3  2013-01-08 2013        0         1         0        0
#...  
#14 2013-01-08 2013       65         0         0        0
#15 2013-01-07 2013        0         1         0        0
#16 2013-01-03 2013        0         0         0        1
#17       <NA> <NA> -3.4, 14 8.3%, 53% 5.0%, 46% 12%, 59%  # the CIs added
```

Hope this helps.